# How to get the previous URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url

Is there any way to get the previous URL in JavaScript?  Something like this:

```
alert("previous url is: " + window.history.previous.href);
```

Is there something like that?  Or should I just store it in a cookie?  I only need to know so I can do transitions from the previous URL to the current URL without anchors and all that.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

```
document.referrer
```

in many cases will get you the URL of the last page the user visited, if they got to the current page by clicking a link (versus typing directly into the address bar, or I believe in some cases, by submitting a form?). Specified by [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95229140). [More here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

`window.history` allows navigation, but not access to URLs in the session for security and privacy reasons. If more detailed URL history was available, then every site you visit could see all the other sites you'd been to.

If you're dealing with state moving around your own site, then it's possibly less fragile and certainly more useful to use one of the normal session management techniques: cookie data, URL params, or server side session info.

Comment: There's also document.referrer, if you arrived at the current page via a link (but not, for example, by bookmark or typing in the address bar).

Comment: i ended up storing the previous url in cookies for the site, `document.referrer` doesn't always work.  `$.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"});`.

Comment: previous is not referrer. don't confuse them

Comment: document.referrer does not save hashes from last url... it only refers to the last url.

Comment: @LancePollard using a cookie for that will cause troubles when page is opened in multiple browser tabs/windows.

Comment: FYI: `document.referrer` will only provide the `hostname` and not the entire `href`.

Comment: If I come to page B.html through a link on A.html, my document.referrer for B.html would be A.html but then from B, I go to a page C.html using a link on B and then if I come back to B using back button, previous URL must be of C but document.referrer would be the link of A. So, we cannot always use document.referrer to get the previous link.

Comment: @TMG if multiple tabs sharing same cookies is concern, we can use sessionStorage

Answer (score 66):

If you want to go to the previous page without knowing the url, you could use the new History api.

```
history.back(); //Go to the previous page
history.forward(); //Go to the next page in the stack
history.go(index); //Where index could be 1, -1, 56, etc.
```

But you can't manipulate the content of the history stack on browser that doesn't support the HTML5 History API

For more information see the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: How to do it with knowing the url, href = ''?

Comment: @summu it is stored in the browser itself

Comment: can yuo tell me the same thing on reactjs?

Comment: 2022 Update: you need to add ```window``` before the ```history``` so you have to write ```window.history.back();```

Comment: Not necessarily, Mike - you can usually assume all the properties of `window` are available in the global context. `window.history` and `history` should _usually_ be the same thing.

Answer (score 42):

If you are writing a web app or single page application (SPA) where routing takes place in the app/browser rather than a round-trip to the server, you can do the following:

```js
window.history.pushState({ prevUrl: window.location.href }, null, "/new/path/in/your/app")
```

Then, in your new route, you can do the following to retrieve the previous URL:

```js
window.history.state.prevUrl // your previous url
```

Comment: Not able to find the prevURl? How to find that? I will be needing two three previous url from history. ?

Answer (score 30):

`document.referrer` is not the same as the actual URL in all situations.

I have an application where I need to establish a frameset with 2 frames. One frame is known, the other is the page I am linking from. It would seem that `document.referrer` would be ideal because you would not have to pass the actual file name to the frameset document.

However, if you later change the bottom frame page and then use `history.back()` it does not load the original page into the bottom frame, instead it reloads `document.referrer` and as a result the frameset is gone and you are back to the original starting window.

Took me a little while to understand this. So in the history array, `document.referrer` is not only a URL, it is apparently the referrer window specification as well. At least, that is the best way I can understand it at this time.

Comment: As of my latest testing 'document.referrer' now just return domain name and not the full URL to avoid tracking.

Answer (score 10):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(document.referrer);
</script>
```

`document.referrer` serves your purpose, but it doesn't work for Internet Explorer versions earlier than IE9.

It will work for other popular browsers, like Chrome, Mozilla, Opera, Safari etc.

Comment: Works in IE 9 for me

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is coming from React-world, I ended up solving my use-case using a combination of `history`-library, useEffect and localStorage

When user selects new project:

```
  function selectProject(customer_id: string, project_id: string){
    const projectUrl = `/customer/${customer_id}/project/${project_id}`
    localStorage.setItem("selected-project", projectUrl)
    history.push(projectUrl)
  }
```

When user comes back from another website. If there's something in localStorage, send him there.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const projectUrl = localStorage.getItem("selected-project")
    if (projectUrl) {
      history.push(projectUrl)
    }
  }, [history])
```

When user has exited a project, empty localStorage

```
  const selectProject = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("selected-project")
    history.push("/")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a `SPA` Single Page App, the easiest way I solved this issue was with local storage as follows:

I stored the url I needed in local storage

```
useEffect(() => {
const pathname = window.location.href; //this gives me current Url
localstorage.setItem('pageUrl',JSON.stringify(pathname))
}, []);
```

On the next screen (or few screens later) I fetched the url can replaced it as follows

```
useEffect(() => {
     const pathname = localstorage.getItem('pageUrl');
     return pathname ? JSON.parse(pathname) : ''
     window.location.href = pathname; //this takes prevUrl from local storage and sets it
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wokaround that work even if document.referrer is empty:

```
let previousUrl = null;

if(document.referrer){
  previousUrl = document.referrer;
  sessionStorage.setItem("isTrickApplied",false);

}else{
let isTrickApplied= sessionStorage.getItem("isTrickApplied");
if(isTrickApplied){
previousUrl = sessionStorage.getItem("prev");
sessionStorage.setItem("isTrickApplied",false);

}else{
history.back(); //Go to the previous page
sessionStorage.setItem("prev",window.location.href);
sessionStorage.setItem("isTrickApplied",true);
history.forward(); //Go to the next page in the stack
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those of you using Node.js and Express can set a session cookie that will remember the current page URL, thus allowing you to check the referrer on the next page load. Here's an example that uses the `express-session` middleware:

```
//Add me after the express-session middleware    
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.session.referrer = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
    next();
});
```

You can then check for the existance of a referrer cookie like so:

```
if ( req.session.referrer ) console.log(req.session.referrer);
```

Do not assume that a referrer cookie always exists with this method as it will not be available on instances where the previous URL was another website, the session was cleaned or was just created (first-time website load).

Answer (score 0):

We cannot know what the previous URL will be in yellow JS, but we can determine whether there is a URL in the search history or not.

As for me, this can sometimes be enough to solve your problem:

```
if (window.history.length <= 1) {
    // Your code here!
}
```