# Auto submit or clicked form based on referrer url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a form auto click based on referrer site..

My url is http://example.com/from/

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="name" value="Jhon" type="text">
<input name="email" value="address@example.com" type="email">
<input name="age" value="28" type="text">
</form>
```

What I would like, is that when a user come from a certain URL the form will automatically be submitted (auto-clicked).  However when the user comes directly to this page, or from a specific site (such as my own) the form will not be submitted.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you tidy up your grammar?  It's really hard to understand what your saying.  Edited grammar, visible after peer review.

Comment: Sorry. my mistake.. with form and from .. sorry. I make a correction. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
string = document.referrer;
```

For more information on this, you should see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer) for more information concerning this.

After you have gotten the URL, you need to decide what to do with it.  You can use document.ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //logic
});
```

Make something that x has the value of "example website" then do:

```
$("#form_id").submit();
```

Else do nothing.

Also, this might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788108/how-to-get-the-previous-page-url-using-js) except that this user purely needs a function to run on the document being finished.  Finally this solution needs [Jquery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
     if (document.referrer == "www.aweber.com")
 $("#sendit").submit();
});
</script>

I use like this... but not work...

Comment: Aren't you missing curly brackets for if statement, although possibly not necessary, might help.  Also, make sure that you have imported jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if (document.referrer == "certain_url")
$("#form_id").submit();
```

Comment: Make sure to enclose it in a document.ready, otherwise it could run before the form is actually loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "match" function to submit the form when the user came from any page of the site anything.com

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var uri = document.referrer;

  if (uri.match(/anything.com/)){
    $("#yourForm").submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you check it out now? There was an "double quotes" missing.