# Is there a JQuery variable that can get the source URL of a page?

Tags: jquery, html, url

I am looking for a Jquery variable that identifies the source url from which a page has been opened. 
The aim is to do a code like this: If you access page A from page B, then… / If you access page A from page C, then…

(note: I don't use php)

Thanks,

Comment: I guess you need to get URL of page from which user came to current page?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: this is what u need then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788108/how-to-get-the-previous-page-url-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `window.location.href;` you get the full URL (https://test.com/itm/012458.html)
With `window.location.origin;` you get the base URL  https://test.com
And with `window.location.pathname;` the path only (/itm/012458.html)
Sorry, I think I misunderstand you. 
You need as another user wrote: `var x = document.referrer;`

Comment: It's indeed document.referrer I need, thank you.

Comment: It will be nice if you accept ma answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Julie. Please don't let you discourage with the '-1'. You are welcome to stackoverflow: every one at the community will do his/her best to help each other, especially new user. So please don't hesitate to ask your questions. Thank you again and Bon courage Julie!