# Javascript: if (previous page == certainurl) { function }

Tags: javascript

I want to execute a function only if the previous page the user visited is on a certain domain. How can this be done using javascript (or jQuery or whatever)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the previous url in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

How about referencing [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.referrer)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.referrer` for this. However, don't count on it always being correct, as some proxies, e.g., don't supply it. It will probably give you some good hits, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's `referrer` object to see where the user came from.

```
if (document.referrer && document.referrer.indexOf("http://" + somehost) > 0){
   // do something
}
```

Be cautions because this not really reliable. You should use some kind of persistent data to know what the user did.