# How to get previous page URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, back-button

How can I design a function that will track the previous page a user has viewed. It will be should be designed to be called on each page.

I will be using a cookies for sure and also they should expire at the end of the visit.

How to achieve that ? I am new to JavaScript :(

Comment: Not possible unless it is on the same domain. document.referrer may hold the previous page but also may not. You can set a cookie, but the user may come from a different page in the same session. Can you explain what you need to do rather than how you think you may need to do it?

Comment: previous page of a particular website or last viewed page from his history???

Comment: Yes previous page of a particular website ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the previous url in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can explain why you need it, we may find a better solution.

You can use histroy.back() function, i think this would help you.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_his_back

Comment: yes, w3school is oldschool but some examples still help. Better not to use it. And yes this doesn't give the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Document referrer will do this, you can then choose to do what ever you want with this url.

```
document.referrer
```