# Backbone.js - Back button (window.history.back) with label of the previous page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'd like to display a back button with a label related to the previous page (a title or something like this) which will be called on the click event. I currently use the `window.history.back()` function on the event but how could I get the label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS out-of-the-box allows to ask for the [previous URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript) but not for the previous title.

You can use other custom implementations. For example with cookies:

```
// code simplified and no tested
function pushHistory() {
  var history = getHistory();
  var newHistory = {
    url:   window.location.pathname,
    title: $("title").text()
  }
  history.push( newHistory );

  $.cookie( "app.history", JSON.parse( history ) );
}

function getHistory(){
  return JSON.parse( $.cookie( "app.history" ) );
}
```

*Note: I'm using [jquery-cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/) to simplify the code.*

Now is up to you to call `pushHistory()` in every page your user visits, and take the proper element in your "app.history" cookie to show the info.