# Is it possible to get URL of previous page visited from browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I am on page A.

Now I click in page A and redirected to page B.

Now I click in page B and redirected to page A.

Here i want to know the url of page B.

I have tried `document.referrer` but its not working.

Comment: Looks like `document.referrer` doesn't work for navigating back. One way would be using one actual page and using `history.pushState`, so that you are able to keep the URLs in memory and using "different" pages at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

document.referrer works when a user clicks on a link to navigate to the current page but I don't think it works when you do a manual redirect in a Javascript function.

The only way I can think of is to store the URL of the page before the user is redirected to your current page.

You could store it in a hidden form or a cookie.

This question has also been asked before and its worth having a quick read through here. [How do you get the previous url in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

I took this cookie example from it to show you what I mean.

```
$.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't *know* the URL of the previous page, but you can link to it using

```
window.history.back();
```

or

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

if you want to know *if* there is a previous page, check

```
window.history.length;
```

If it's more than 0, there is a prev page. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history