# How to get the previous page value using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the value of my previous page in my redirected page. For example: I have the page A and the page B.

The page B has 3 fieldsets, but by default, it shows only 2.
But, I have a link to page B in my page A, and if I click on this link my page A will be redirected to page B and show the third fieldset.

I tried using History and referrer. But I didn't get any result.

My progress so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var ex=document.referrer;
            alert(ex);
        });
```

(just to test if it's working.)

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005620/is-it-possible-to-get-url-of-previous-page-visited-from-browser-using-javascript check this link. would be helpful

Comment: can you use querystrings in your code?if yes, you can add a querystring to the link in pageA and then check for the querystring in pageB.

Comment: You can store previous page value in local storage & then you can access that local storage value in next page.