# How to get the previous page Url in javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am redirecting from other site to my site particular page. I need that Url from which site I am redirected.

I have tried document.refferer but it is alert the current page Url.

Please suggest me anyone how to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can look at; 1.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788108/how-to-get-the-previous-page-url-using-js   2.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript                             3.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005620/is-it-possible-to-get-url-of-previous-page-visited-from-browser-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with document.referrer instead of document.refferer ?

Comment: else try with window.history.back()