# javascript browser history listing

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am familiar with the `window.history.back()` and the `window.history.forward()` javascript objects. But is there a method of creating an array with the last  "X" number pages viewed.

Comment: you can append an array saved in localStorage each time a page loads...

Comment: [window.history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history) does not have such methods available for web content.

Answer (score 30):

No, this would be a huge security problem.  You can get `history.length` to count them if you wish.

Comment: If you can't then how is Google doing it?

Comment: Because they doing it with a web browser not Javascript DOM ._.

Comment: @CodeApprentice, Google isn't doing it.  What makes you think they are?

Comment: @Brad@CodeApprentice, Google isn't doing it. What makes you think they are?  Go to:http://www.tomsguide.com/us/firefox-chrome-internet-explorer-history-sniffing-history-hijacking,news-9230.html

Comment: @CodeApprentice, I suggest reading an article written by someone with some technical competence, and from a technical point of view.  Google, and other ad networks, use cookies.  If publisher A and B both share a common ad network, then it is possible for the ad network to set a cookie on site from publisher A and read that cookie from publisher B's site.  The cookie doesn't actually break any rules... it's on the ad network's domain.  This has nothing to do with your actual browser history.

Comment: It's possible to access the browser's history in Chrome using the [chrome.history](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/) API, but this is only available in browser extensions.

Comment: How would it be a huge security problem if it would just show the history of the pages of the current domain? I could track that info on the server side anyway.

Comment: @user764754 My understanding of the question is that they were asking generally, not just the current origin.

Answer (score 7):

Check out:

[How do you get the previous url in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

In short you can get the number of previous sites visited (`history.length`) but not the url's.