# Getting all the previous URL in a single tab across different domains in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get all the URL's traversed in a single tab across different domains using JavaScript?
I tried localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies, history.go and document.referrer but I am still stuck. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access my entire browsing history via Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369829/access-my-entire-browsing-history-via-javascript)

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032415/javascript-browser-history-listing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "using JavaScript via a script element in a webpage": **No!**. That would expose users to a massive invasion of privacy.

Browser vendors take active steps to prevent that sort of information from leaking: To the extent of making it impossible to change the size of an element using the `:visited` pseudo-class so you can't change the style with CSS and then read it with JS.