# How to loop through JavaScript window.history state objects?

Tags: javascript, browser-history, html5-history

At some point I am replacing or pushing state objects to my history.
Is it possible to **loop through** the history to obtain these state objects?
I am only interested in the state objects that my page has created, and so I cannot see a security violation.

Currently, I am only able to see a practical solution by combining sessionStorage and the history API.

Are there any other ways?

Comment: For security reasons I don't think you can

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17032415/2397327) give you an answer? I don't see why `sessionStorage` wouldn't be a good way to go about it.

Comment: And yes, as @charlietfl says, there would be security problems if you could all the history state data from past websites visited by the user.