# How to read Page history in Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, php, html, browser-history

I need to do following steps before using history.go

1. I need to read the recent histories for my page
2. if history matches with the link specified by me then it should open link
3. or else it should alert some warning

Please help to fix this issue

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not possible, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3528331/1267304).

Comment: I hope that it is not possible, actually...

Answer (score 0):

In general javascript cannot read the browser history directly. There is a workaround for this issue desribed [here](http://www.dicabrio.com/javascript/steal-history.php).

For the described requirement I would recommend to use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

**you can manipulate the browser history using window object.**

use [history api](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/) I think you may complete using this.

see the [demo](http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/fluffy) of history api

I hope it will help full to you.