# Get previous URL and display on page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a jobs website with several different job description pages and with 1 application page with a form.

i.e.

```
/admin-clark -> /application
/sale-rep -> /application
```

I would like to pre-populate an input field in the form with the id #jobTitle.

I would like to do the following-

- Get the previous URL
- Store it in local storage
- Sanatize url(remove dashes etc)
- Use jQuery to fill in the field with id jobTitle

Or is a there a better way of doing this?

This is what I have so far

```
var pathname = window.location.path.replace(/^\?$/, '').toUpperCase();
localStorage.setItem("pathname ", pathname );
$('#jobTitle').val(pathname);
```

Comment: Why not pass through a reference to the application page of the page they came from? Something like :`application.php?job=admin-clerk`.

Comment: please describe your question. what you want to pre-populate and when? What is #jobTittle? and what is relation of previous url ?

Comment: @BenM, that's a good idea, how would I append this string to the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in many cases(Not in every case) will get you the URL of the last page if they got to the current page by clicking a link using `document.referrer;` See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer)

You can also take help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)