# How to redirect depending on where the user came from in javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

If a person comes to my site  X1 from site X2 then it should redirect to site X3..  if a person directly open the site X1 it should not redirect to site X3.  you can use any programming to do this..

WHERE X1 ,X2 and X3 are the three different sites..

Comment: Something like this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript

Comment: What happens if X1 is not directly opened but also isn't coming from site X2?

Comment: It's not possible, in general, to know where the user comes from. Some browsers may send a referer header, but don't take it for granted.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the referer

```
var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref.match(/^http?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?SITEX2\.com(\/|$)/i)) {
  window.location.replace("http://SITEX3.com");
}
```