# How to get previous url including hash fragment using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the previous url to redirect to the previous page. I have url like `www.mysite.com/users/register/#1`.

I use `document.referrer` to get the previous url,but it doesn't return **hash part**(`#1`). How to get the previous url including hash part?

Comment: And it's just within your own domain, no referrers from cross origins? You could maybe store the previous url in local storage or a cookie ?

Comment: Is this just asking about referrals within your own site? Or from a different origin?

Comment: Have you looked at window.history?

Comment: `window.history` only has a length, and back, forward etc. no url's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the previous url in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Comment: @adeneo Eh... read the question: "I need to get the previous url to redirect to the previous page". So... **window.history.back()**, hm?

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors - if that's the only goal, and the OP doesn't need the URL, `history.back` would be a viable answer *(if it includes the hash ?)*

Comment: @adeneo: `history.back()` is like the back button, so yes, it takes you back with the previous hash in place. So `window.history` can address the final part of the question, but not the headline (actually getting the URL).

Answer (score 11):

> How to get previous url **including hash fragment** using JavaScript?

As you've noted, the hash fragment part of that means you can't use `document.referrer`.

**If the previous page was on the same origin**: You'd need to have code on that page recording the full URL, for instance in `sessionStorage`.

On the previous page, perhaps each time `hashChange` is fired:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("last-url", location);
```

On the new page, to get the URL:

```
var lastUrl = sessionStorage.getItem("last-url");
```

**If the previous page was on a different origin**: I'm fairly certain you can't.

> I need to get the previous url to redirect to the previous page.

Actually, you don't. You can just [use `history.go(-1)` or `history.back()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) to do that, which work regardless of the origin of the previous page.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can use onhashchange event.
When url is changed,it produces a event with old url and new url.
The oldurl has even the hash part

Answer (score 1):

try for previous url,

```
    function backtopage() {

    window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: The original answer was just completely wrong. The updated answer just duplicates a small part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind('statechange',function(){
    // Prepare Variables
    var State = History.getState(),
        url = State.url,
        states = History.savedStates,
        prevUrlIndex = states.length - 2,
        prevUrl = states[prevUrlIndex].hash;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
Try this one::

In previous page url:
www.mysite.com/users/register/#1

In Current Page:
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrerUrl =   document.referrer.replace("#","e");
   var correctUrl=referrerUrl.replace("e","#");
});
```

Comment: As the question clearly says: `document.referrer` doesn't include the hash fragment.