# How can I retrieve the previous URL in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I know I can get the current URL using `$location.search()` and `$location.path()` but I need a way to get previous one.  Can I use a global variable or something like that?

Comment: Would `document.referrer` work for you? In that case this question might be a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular `$rootScope` will have the all information across your all app components.

Here below `$location` service injected on `$rootscope` will give you the route information.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, current, previous) {
        console.log("Previous URL" +previous);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use for example ui-router to control the flow of your application and with this library it's easy to implement previousState by saving it in *$stateChangeSuccess* event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this when listening on the $routeChangeSuccess event. Parameters are currentRoute and previousRoute. You can also use $locationChangeStart and save the current route yourself.

See here:

[AngularJS $route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

[AngularJS $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)