# how to store path name value in local storage or cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage

I have angular app and based on previous path name not page name i want to store the value either in cookie or local storage

Path name of first page is `/content/drive.html/find-drive`
Path name of second page is `/content/drive.html/drive-results`

When I am on the second page I want to store `find-drive` value in cookie

Similarly

Path name of first page is `/content/drive.html/find-drive-advanced`
Path name of second page is `/content/drive.html/drive-results`

When I am on second page i want to store the previous path location in my cookie or local storage.for this scenario i want to store"find-drive-advanced"

Note: `document.referrer` doesn't work, and `window.parent.URl` doesn't work

Comment: you can try the following solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933673/how-can-i-retrieve-the-previous-url-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage`

Say that `url1 = '/content/drive.html/find-drive'`, and `url2 = '/content/drive.html/drive-results'`

just save them like so:

```
localStorage.setItem('url1', url1);
localStorage.setItem('url2', url2);
```

to retrieve the value, just write

```
var url1 = localStorage.getItem('url1');
```