# How to get the previous previous url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, window, browser-history

I would like to get the previous previous url/uri in javascript?
I searched for all different kind of APIs but of no help.

If you have any solution for the same, it will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the previous url in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Comment: create a local storage option. Store the urls visited, so that you can retrieve the later.