# Javascript previous URL after pressing browser back button

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am not very experienced with Javascript and i have implement simple redirection with Javascript but now i want to get URL (previous) when the user will press browser back button after that redirection.
I am trying to get previous URL with "document.referrer" but it is not returning correct previous url.
I am redirecting my web page with this.

```
window.open('https://weather.com');
```

But after this redirection when the user will press browser back button, i want to get back this url from my own web page because i want to track that URL and implement some more functionality.
I ll need help to complete this process and i will really appreciate your help.
Thank you!!

Comment: I guess you are confusing jQuery and javascript, jQuery is just a javascript-library. Your question is about javascript functionality. Please edit your question with javascript-tag and remove jQuery tag. Also corect the text.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. I appreciate it. I know JQuery is javascript library but now i am trying to get back that url after redirection. We can get that from browser history or from cookies but i am not sure so if you will guide me about this that will be very much helpful for me to complete this process. Thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the previous url in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Comment: Without [mcve] it is unlikely we can help you. We need to see the problem, the code you provided does not showcase anything.

Comment: if you are working in same domain, you can save address into localstorage/session storage and keep you own history

Comment: Thanks all of you for your response and time. I am redirecting my web page with Java script and after that redirection when the user will press browser back button then i want to get back previous url as i have mentioned above in my question. Right now i am thinking to use cookies for this purpose.

Comment: I am not redirecting my page to same domain. That will be an external url.