# passing value to another page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, anchor

I have two  tags in page0.html. I want to show in page1.html which a tag was clicked:

```
<a href="page1.html" target="_blank">A</a>
<a href="page1.html" target="_blank">B</a>
```

I want to page1.html look something like:

> Link A was pressed
>
> or
>
> Link B was pressed.

is that possible using Javascript? or should i use something else?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `?` in page0.html

```
<a href="page1.html?a" target="_blank">A</a>
<a href="page1.html?b" target="_blank">B</a>
```

In page1.html

```
 var parts = window.location.search.substr(1);
 alert('Link '+parts+' was pressed');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do add hash into url(href) and access by `window.location.hash`

page0.html

```
<a href="page1.html#A" target="_blank">A</a>
<a href="page1.html#B" target="_blank">B</a>
```

page1.html

```
console.log("Link "+window.location.hash.substring(1)+" was pressed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers could be an alternative. I would rather suggest to use the document.referrer for identifying the same.
For more details, please refer Stack overflow query:
[How do you get the previous url in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inline by onclick event

```
  <a href="page1.html#A" onclick= "alert('Page1 was click') " target="_blank">A</a>
  <a href="page1.html#B" onclick= "alert('Page2 was click') " target="_blank">B</a>
```