# Get previous URL from window.history

Tags: javascript

How to get the previous page URL? can we get this using the window.history ?

Note - We only need that URL and no need to perform any redirection.

Comment: you can use `document.referrer` , good luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the previous URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Comment: @ChrisMartin I've already gone through that link but the approach suggested in that, not working. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: What you have tried? What doesn't work? What are your expected results and what you are getting?

Comment: And no, `window.history` doesn't give information about the previous URL.

Answer (score 3):

I am using `document.referrer`, it will return the previous URL you have visited

EDIT: I also found this code snippet, where you store the previous URL using cookies.

```
$.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"});
```

You can assign the cookie in a variable to retrieve its value or something like that

Comment: Thanks for your kind input and I really appreciate this. But No, It is giving the incorrect result. I've already tried this but in some cases, it not works. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `incorrect` results? What is the expected result and what are you getting? Give examples of what you've tried.

Comment: @JeremiahCabigting appreciate you helping but the OP hasn't made clear what doesn't work, if they have a somewhat different system they should specify it in their post, but no code snippet have been given at all.

Comment: @DeepakKamatIt's just a small issue and you thought that I should have given a code snippet & screencast video for this? I don't want to spend my time on this activities. That's the reason why I didn't use the StackOverflow frequently.  The guys here are very rude even they don't know about the sense of talking professionally.