# Get the URL from previous page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have page A and B. in my page A, I have link that direct me to page B. 
What I want to do is, when I click the link in page A, it will open page B, and also give me alert of page A`s URL. Here is what I try:

page A:

```
<html>
<head>
<a href="file:///C:/Users/jason/Desktop/pageb.html">click me</a> 
</head>
</html>
```

page B:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var oldURL = document.referrer;
alert(oldURL);

</script>
</head>
```

It opens the page B when I click it, but the alert is blank. How can i do this?

Comment: Move the `<a>` tag out of the `<head>` element and place it into a `<body>` element.

Comment: I am sorry, i edit the question.. I alert the oldURL now. But it is not working

Comment: @raspisurya - It works fine as it is with just some minor changes. You don't need to do `window.open()` or use local storage or anything crazy like that. The original issue with the code has to do with the `file:///` URI you've used for page B. There will be no referrer. But if you run this code from a server (with the `<a>` in the correct place) it works fine. Here's proof: http://plnkr.co/edit/WMaE76VndKpQRGQ01iTz?p=preview

Comment: i don't understand why it give me the blank result in my local? what is the difference

Comment: Rather than explain this here, I put the explanation into an answer. It accurately and correctly addresses your question. The other answers do not address the real issue.  I would appreciate if you would accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the previous URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
 alert(document.referrer);
```

That should alert the referrer.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I moved this out of the comments because it describes the **real** issue.

The original issue with the code has to do with the `file:///` URI you've used for page B. There will be no `referrer`. But if you run this code from a server it works fine. Here's proof: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WMaE76VndKpQRGQ01iTz?p=preview)

When you load a file from the file system (using `file://` protocol) the `referrer` header is not set. You can easily see the difference if you open the network panel in dev tools and look at the headers for both pages. Opened with `file:///` no headers, from Plunkr has correct `referrer` header.

So your code works fine (but the anchor tag should be moved).

You don't need to do window.open() or use local storage or anything crazy like that.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<a href="file:///C:/Users/jason/Desktop/pageb.html">click me</a>` out of the `head` tag. And print `oldURL` variable insted of  `window.location.href` which is the current URL.

Page A

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<a href="file:///C:/Users/jason/Desktop/pageb.html">click me</a> 

</html>
```

Page B

```js
var oldURL = document.referrer;
alert(oldURL);
```

Comment: I have tried this but this is not working in my local PC. still blank alert comes out. I put the pagea.html and pageb.html in my desktop

Comment: It's blank because there's no origin. Put <meta name="referrer" content="origin"> in the <head> to get an origin for a locally-opened html file. Even better, install a localhost and run it on there.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your latest visited url in sessionStorage
on Page A:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('url', window.location.href);
```

on Page B

```
alert(sessionStorage.getItem('url'))
```

Comment: what if I don't have any access to edit the source page A? what I can do is only in page B

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in the URL:

```
 window.open("b.html?referer=" + window.location.href);
```

You can also use the `opener` object to get a parent window's variable:

a.html

```
<html>
 <script>
   var referrer = window.location.href;
   var win = window.open("b.html");
 </script>
</html>
```

b.html

```
<html>
 <script>
   alert(window.opener.referrer);
 </script>
</html>
```

As @RandyCasburn mentioned above, you also have to move the  tag from the head to the body for it to be visible:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="file:///C:/Users/jason/Desktop/pageb.html">click me</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With the `<a>` in the correct place, the use of `window.open()` is unnecessary as a solution because the anchor tag will accomplish the goal without code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.referrer

Refer the following code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Alert</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in/" onclick="onLinkClick()">Link</a>
    <script>

        function onLinkClick() {
            alert("Redirected from==>"+document.referrer);

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```