# Get previous URL through js in IE > 10 browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

I'm trying to get the previous URL in chrome via `document.referrer` but this is not working in IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the previous URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Comment: @VenkateshManohar I already checked the link and it did not resolve my issue, my question is how to make work document.referrer in IE browsers

Comment: In that case you have to clearly mention what all options have you tried and how exactly are you trying to use document.referrer.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my side, I have tried to create a sample and using the document.referrer property to get the URI of the page that "linked" to this page in the page load method, it seems that everything works well in IE 10+, I could get the url. Can you share the related code? or try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error?

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT thanks for the efforts, actually it was an issue at my end, the browser is returning null every time, but after restarting pc it's working, don't know how but it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.referrer` is working on IE10+ and edge browsers, this issue is only at my side, the browser was returning null every time but after restarting pc everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`document.referrer` works on IE9+ so you can use this to get history url.