# How to get previous URL after navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I have implemented a `previous button` on my page, which navigates me back
to the previous page.

i.e, `Page A` -> `Page B` (has previous button)
How Can I find the link of `Page A` so that it will take me back to `Page A` using `javascript/jQuery`

I tried this link

> [How to get the previous URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

I used this `history.back()` but that works with onclick

How to get href.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need an `href` value? Please specify a case where `onclick()` is unsuitable.

Comment: Have you tried this? `document.referrer`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the previous URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer):

```js
console.log(document.referrer);
/* The above logs this page because Stack Snippets are run on stacksnippets.net,
   and therefore your browser went there from this page 
   (because you're running the code here).
*/
```