# How to get Previous visited page URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to get the previous page URL? can we get this using the window.history ?
Note - We only need that URL and no need to perform any redirection.

I have tried document.referrer
but it's not working in Chrome.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            
            alert("previous url is: " + document.referrer);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the previous URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Comment: document.referrer works fine in chrome

Comment: `but it's not working in Chrome`: what is the output? Please paste it into the question.

Comment: Could be down to Chrome Version? See: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default