# Javascript get previous page URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, back-button

I am not able to get previous page URL using "referrer". Suppose I am going from page A to B. And by clicking browser back button I am returning back to Page A again. Now I want to check my previous page URL is B. How can I check it with Javascript.
I have to check this on page load. When returning back to Page A, I did not any value.

```
<script>          
 window.onload = function(){                           
    alert('hit '+document.referrer);              
 }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the previous URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)

Comment: document.referrer is not working in chrome.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please show us the issue by editing the question with a [mcve].

Comment: @evolutioxboxUpdated my question

Answer (score 0):

If you have inner website's pages on the same root (folder), you can go through these pages in this way:
Also you can a tag wrap with button tag.

```html
<a href = "A page.html">A page</a>
<a href = "B page.html">B page</a>
```

Comment: I'm confused. What does this have to do with the question?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.back()
}
</script>
```

```html
 <html>
<head>
<!--Insert script here -->
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">

</body>
</html>
```

Or read: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_history.asp)

Comment: I want to get the Previous page URL