# How can I access browser history with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need user history for some redirection. How can I access it? If I couldn't there are the best practices to store the user history in my app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to get the previous URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)? In some cases you can use `document.referrer`. Otherwise, you'll need to implement your own logic to keep track of the visited pages.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing browser history is not directly linked with NextJS.
If you want to access browser history, you can directly access it with window history object (Browser Object Model).

Answer (score -1):

In Nextjs use nextjs router hook for handling redirections.

> Also you can use window or document browser objects, but make sure they are [client rendered](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) instead of server, as they will be undefined in server.

more you can read [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

Comment: I need to know the previous page. I can't find solution with Next-router

Comment: do you need to go to the previous page ?

Comment: Nope, I need to know what is the previous page?

Comment: do you want to know the path ?

Comment: Yeap, I need to know the path.

Comment: How did you come to know the path @kursademirtas