# can two websites talk or share any kind of data each other(reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, single-sign-on, referrer

Like knowing the previous url before coming to this page(not within same website but say two different websites). I tried consoling document.referrer in localhost in react, but returns an empty string. Is there a way to know the previous url, from where you came to the current page(not in same website but two different websites)and also send data from one to another from frontend? Like an sso website?

Comment: There are some good answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe to communicate between 2 separate websites -> https://medium.com/@saurabhbhatiazx/cross-domain-i-frame-communication-using-html5-56144f520ebf