# How can i get previous page url in Kentico 12 PE?

Tags: kentico

How can i get previous page url in Kentico 12 PE?
Visitor.GetUrlReferrer() macro and document.referrer js are always empty.

I want to change my webpart variant via url of previous page. image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LbQt.png)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Kentico macros when you can use plain JavaScript.

```
window.history.previous.href
```

[How to get the previous URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript)